# Combine data from different rows base on column value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a excel file that contain daily order record and I need to summarize the order detail base on different staff.

I would like to combine the rows base on same Staff ID and divide to different group.
All order with the same Staff ID(Column B) will divide to a same group, the quantity of item A to item X of the order within a group will sum individual, each group will retain the first order record only and the other order id(Column A) within the group will mark in the remark column(Column G).

I have a macro with many for-loop & if statement to finish the task, but I don't have any idea how to simplify or modified it. Could someone can give me some suggestion?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything for you.

```
Private Sub test()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'sum the quantity of item
For Z = 2 To lastrow
If Range("F" & Z) <> "" Then
    ordercount = 2
    For c = 2 To lastrow
        If Z <> c Then
            If Range("F" & Z) = Range("F" & c) Then
                For i = 0 To 9
                    temp = Cells(Z, 3 + i) + Cells(c, 3 + i)
                    If temp <> 0 Then
                        Cells(Z, 3 + i) = temp
                    End If
                Next i
                Range("G" & Z) = Range("G" & Z).Value & "No." & ordercount 
                & " " & Range("A" & c).Value & Chr(10)
                ordercount = ordercount + 1
                End If
        End If
    Next c
End If
orderno = Range("G" & Z).Value
If orderno <> "" Then
    Range("G" & Z) = Left(orderno, Len(orderno) - 1)
End If
Next Z
'delete the other record within the same group
For Z = 2 To lastrow
If Range("F" & Z) <> "" Then
    For c = 2 To lastrow
        If Z <> c Then
            If Range("F" & Z) = Range("F" & c) Then
                Rows(c).Delete
                c = c - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End If
Next Z
End Sub
```

Sample:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do what you expect, but the loop starts from the bottom of the data and moves to the second row, as when deleting rows it is advisable to work upwards, so as not to miss the comparison against any row when deleting rows:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop from last row to second (missing headers)
    CheckID = ws.Cells(i, 2) 'get the Staff ID to check
    For x = (i - 1) To 2 Step -1 'second loop for comparison
        If ws.Cells(x, 2) = CheckID Then 'if ID's match
            ws.Cells(i, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 3) + ws.Cells(x, 3) 'add values for Item A
            ws.Cells(i, 4) = ws.Cells(i, 4) + ws.Cells(x, 4) 'add values for Item B
            ws.Cells(i, 5) = ws.Cells(i, 5) + ws.Cells(x, 5) 'add values for Item C
            ws.Cells(i, 6) = ws.Cells(i, 6) 'get the Group Number
            ws.Cells(i, 7) = ws.Cells(i, 7) & Chr(10) & ws.Cells(x, 1) 'Add remark
            ws.Rows(x).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delete row
            i = i - 1 'adjust counter
            LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get new last row
        End If
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked as well and give me some idea to modify my other VBA. Thank you very much.